# ways of getting my location on android

Tags: android, service, location, difference

This may be a kinda odd question but I am new at Android development and I'm having trouble to learn how to retrieve the user's location to my application. I have looked for this topic but I just can't find a statisfying answer.

To get the user location I have found two ways:

1. http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html . This one is using what I think is the new Google Services release which uses a LocationClient to connect to Google Services and retrieve the location.
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html . The other one is using the android.location class and a LocationManager to retrieve the location.

The thing is that I don't get the difference between using one way or the other, which one is better??

And another question is that in the second way you can specify which location provider you want to use, if the GPS provider or the Network provider and in the first one you can't, but in the first paragraph it says that it uses the location sensors that are currently active for the device. Does this mean that I don't have to worry about choosing between both services??

I am using Android Studio and I have set up the new Google Services release, I just need to know the pros and cons between both ways to know which one to use and to begin learning.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the second link:

> The Google Location Services API, part of Google Play Services, provides a more powerful, high-level framework that automatically handles location providers, user movement, and location accuracy. It also handles location update scheduling based on power consumption parameters you provide. In most cases, you'll get better battery performance, as well as more appropriate accuracy, by using the Location Services API.

I would highly recommend you to watch the last I/O video to get a simple explanation from Reto Meier about the new Location Provider: http://youtu.be/GcNNx2zdXN4?t=14m29s (I suggest you to watch the entire clip btw, it's inspiring).

Comment: I watched the video and he uses the implementation of the first link with the LocationClient but in the second link it says that the LocationManager is a better and more powerful way of using the Google Play Services... so I'm confused lol is it supossed that the second way (with the LocationManager) is better than using the LocationClient??

Comment: Where the second link says that the LocationManager is better? They say to use the new one, so the LocationClient. Btw, LocationClient is better than LocationManager. :)

Comment: Well it says it's more powerful so I assumed it was better lol but anyways, thanks for your help!! :) My app is working with the LocationClient and I'm ready to move on :)